# Predicting breaking force of beam per length based on one testing

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, beam, strength

I've made a plywood carbon sheet and tested its breaking force, for a 200mm long, 50mm wide, 16mm thick it was 100kg +-

I was wondering if it's enough to help me predict what will be the breaking force when its the same beam but 1000mm long and 2000mm?

Is it linear? am I'm missing some vars in order to calculate it?

It's harder and more costly for me to test longer beam, as I'm in the prototyping phase and trying to determine to right thickness and plywood carbon ratio of the beam

Comment: 1 test isn't enough to predict the strength of that specific piece of material.

Comment: @TigerGuy Can you clarify why 1 test isn't enough? Is it because of variations in the material? If 1 isn't enough,  how many or what test is sufficient?

Comment: @TigerGuy I can do more, how much do I need? I just can't do it on long beams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tiger Guy says one test is absolutely not reliable. There are extensive tests under precisely controlled conditions by commercial structural lumber manufacturers. here is one. [source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822320313477)

But let's say you did a hundred tests and the average was 100kg.
A rough relation between rapture load and beam properties, when a load F is applied at mid-span with length L, is

$$M_{rapture}= \frac{F_{rapture}L}{4}=Constant\quad F_{rapture}\propto \frac{1}{L}$$

So if we keep all dimensions the same except the length L, if you multiply the L=200mmby 5 to get L=1000mm you can expect it will barely support,
$$F_{1000mm}= 100/5=20kg$$

And for l=2000mm
$$F_{2000mm}= 100/10=10kg.$$

.

[image: beam with load F]